# Filtrar datatable que contengan al menos un no

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable

Se que el título es poco claro pero a ver si la explicación ayuda mas. Tengo una pagina hecha mediante php  que hace una llamada mediante Ajax a un controlador que le devuelve una lista de usuarios. Dicha lista es formateada en una datatable, obteniendo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el select del filtro manejo tres opciones: 1) Todos los usuarios, 2) Los usuarios que tienen todo marcado como si y 3) los usuarios que al menos tienen un no.

Para ello tengo el siguiente código:

```
$('#CookiesFilter').on('change', function() {
    var select = $(this).val();

    if (select === '2') {
        table.columns([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]).search('Si').draw();
    } else if (select === '3') {
        table.columns([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]).search('No').draw();
    } else {
        table.columns([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]).search('').draw();
    }
});
```

La opción de todos si funciona bien. Pero no así la función de algún no. De hecho tal cual la tengo ahí puesta hace bien lo que se supone que tiene que hacer, devolver solo aquellos usuarios que tienen todo marcado como no. Pero llevo dos días probando opciones para obtener lo que realmente necesito y no hay manera.

¿Alguien me podria ayudar y decirme como seria posible conseguir un filtro que hiciera que, aplicado a la imagen adjunta, me devolviera la primera y segunda fila? Gracias de antemano

EDITO: Añado como tengo la petición ajax

```
ajax: {
        url: "controller.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        dataSrc: "",
        data: () => ({
            action: "getUsersCookies",

        }),
        error: (error) => {
            if (error.responseJSON) {
                alertify.error(error.responseJSON.message);
                $("#table > tbody").html(`
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="100" style="text-align:center">Se ha producido un error, por favor intentelo de nuevo.</td>
                            </tr>
                        `);
            }
        },
    },
```

En la opcion success intente poner un console.log de data pero no me mostraba nada

Comment: Y no seria más fácil, filtrar el arreglo que te devuelve la petición `ajax`, y con esa información filtrada, borrar y dibujar la tabla nuevamente?,  si necesitas reformular te pregunta para realizar mi sugerencia te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta e incluir la estructura de la informacion que te duelve tu petición, sin incluir datos sensibles o que afecten la privacidad/confidencialidad.

Comment: Para serte sincero, estoy empezando a pelearme con javascript y familia y aunque voy pillando experiencia, aun estoy verde. Te digo esto porque mi petición esta tomada de otra simialr que hay en el proyecto y lo adapte. Pero antes pasarlo a la tabla intente ver el contenido con el tipico console.log y no lo consegui, asi que el arreglo se que llega pero no se como manejarlo. De todas formas edito la pregunta para añadir la petición ajax

Comment: Hola si te funciona la opción **todos los que tienen todo marcado como si** exclúyelos **toma su negación**, puedes recorrer la tabla completa eligiendo los que no estén en la respuesta a la consulta.

Comment: No se si te refieres a usar algo como esto

```else if (select === '3') {
        table.columns([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]).search('^((?!Si).)*$').draw();
    }```

Pero no me funciono